# React: How to preserve scroll position when coming back from external sites

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I have a React app using `react-router` v3.2.0 and with the server side rendering implemented.

It generates an article view dynamically and receives the full HTML contents from backend built with Node.js/ExpressJS.

Some articles have links to external sites and the problem is that when you click on those links and press the Back button of browsers, the browser goes back to the previous article page, but it loses a previous scroll position, always scrolling up to the top.

Is it possible to preserve the scroll position when coming back from external sites?

Some suggests to save the scroll position in `localStorage` when a route changes and manually set the scroll position when coming back, in the `componentDidMount()`, but I think there should be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: `localStorage` seems to be most elegant way rather than persisting the data back into a database. But I am interested to see what solutions there possibly could be.